# Launch a bash sub-shell and expect a command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

From a shell script, how can I launch a bash sub-shell for the user & wait for the user to type exit at the bash sub-shell prompt?

I tried `bash -c expect -c 'expect "exit" {send "Exiting\n"}';` but it is not working. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you expect "expect" to be:

```
$ type -a expect
bash: type: expect: not found
```

Here a simple example that might give clues:

```
$ bash -c 'echo "Hi, I am alive." ; read -p "Press ENTER to exit> " ans ; echo "You typed $ans"' 
Hi, I am alive.
Press ENTER to exit> exit
You typed exit
```

`man bash`, `help read` and the Bash guides at http://www.tldp.org/guides.html might be of help.